# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

При вызове POST API на мой сервер получаем такую ошибку.

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
>   WebServiceCommunal.Gateway.EasyPay_Gateway.Check(String[] inputs,
>   Int32 language, String ServiceId, String Currency) in
>   C:\TfsRepo2018\TerminalSoft\Backend\Client
>   Layer\Getways\WebServiceCommunal\WebServiceCommunal\Gateway\EasyPay_Gateway.cs:line
>   72 {Status:ConnectFailure;Response:;Message:Unable to connect to the
>   remote
>   server;Data:System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal;InnerException:System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   (0x80004005): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions ххх.хх.ххх.ххх:80

При вызове по Постман все работает отлично , но когда компания вызывает тот же API то такая ошибка.
В чем проблема? Техподдержка хостинга говорит что в файрволах ничего не блокируется. Логи я вижу, все кажется ок. тогда в чем проблема?

Пример: https://url/check/ вот так выглядит моя ссылка. check это папка где находится index.php, сейчас я  убрал последний "/" знак и компания получает 404. Но по постман я опять получаю 200 и все ок. Что не так?

И у меня в хостинге стоит сайт на Вордпресс. Может это блокируется Вордпрессом?

Comment: asp.net и asp.net-core - это _разные_ технологии. Определитесь, что у вас. Аналогично, определитесь: у вас mvc или web-api. Не надо лепить все метки подряд. Зачем метка php?

Comment: Скорее всего техподдержка хостинга всё-таки блокирует исходящие на порт 80, или вообще все исходящие. Напишите простой пример - тупо запрос на 80 порт в контроллере, через webclient, и попробуйте вызвать. Если упадет - значит хостер шалит